# How to create (C#) Regular Expression Rules

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Can we use regular expressions to find out if a string follows these rules?

- Not have upper-case letters.
- Begin with a letter.
- Have at least 1 digit(s) not at the beginning and end.
- Have up to 8 alphanumeric
- Does NOT have any symbols like @#$ characters (symbols like !@#$%^&*()-+).

Comment: Yes, this can be done via regular expressions. Any other questions? If you meant to ask for a regular expression that conforms to the above rules, I would want to know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: are values sandwhiched between characters or on individual lines?

Comment: I am going to say this is for password validation

Comment: In my opinion it's much easier using the plain string methods (Contains, StartsWith etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've updated the regular-expression in the code with one which looks to work.

`@"^[a-z](?=[a-z0-9@#\$]*[0-9][a-z0-9@#\$]*)[a-z0-9@#\$]{0,6}[a-z@#\$]$"`

**EDIT**: I've tweaked the code. One of the tests was `aa1@aaaa` marked as being expected to fail when it should succeed as pointed out by Douglas.

I've verified that the regular-expression offered by Douglas works just as well and its shorter too.

---

Not an answer as such, but here's a quick test-rig. I've used the regular expression and tests from @ShaunWilde's answer.

Unfortunately, the tests don't return the expected results :-|.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StackOverflow.RegularExpressions
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var validString =
                new Regex(@"^[a-z][a-z\d!@#$%\^&*()\-+]{0,7}$(?<=\d\D+)",
                          RegexOptions.Compiled);

            var testsAndExpectedResults = new List<Tuple<string, bool>>
                                              {
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("a1@aaaaa", true),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("a@1aaaaa", true),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("aa@aaaaa", false),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("a1@aaaaaaa", false),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("a1@aaaa", true),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("1a1@aaaa", false),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("aa1@aaaa", true),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("Aa1@aaaa", false),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("Aa1@aaaA", false),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("aA1@aaaA", false),
                                                  new Tuple<string, bool>("#A@a1aaaaa", false)
                                              };

            testsAndExpectedResults.ForEach(t =>
                                            Console.WriteLine("With '{0}' expected {1}, got {2}", t.Item1, t.Item2,
                                                              validString.IsMatch(t.Item1))
                );

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried ShaunWilde's tests with @Douglas' answer and that doesn't seem to quite do the job either.

Comment: I'd advocate splitting the tests out, if the "policy" of what makes a valid string changes it'll be easier to maintain.

Comment: It is the test that is incorrect, not my regex. `"aa1@aaaa"` meets all conditions set out in the question; yet, it is defined as expected to fail in the test.

Comment: @Douglas I've tweaked the tests accordingly and updated my answer and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 2):

From memory;

- not have uppercase `"^[^A-Z]*$"`
- begin with letter `"^[A-Za-z].*"`
- have at lest 1 digit `".*\d+.*"`
- have up to 8 alphanumeric or @#$ chars `"[A-Za-z0-9@#\$]{,8}"`

Now you should be able to combine the "have" clauses in a "any 1 of these way" fairly simply, but I dont know if its possible to actually have a single regex expression that is logically a "not this, but one of this, this or this".
Perhaps other posters can do that!

If your unsure of your regex expressions I can recommend "[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)" a very useful free regex exploring tool. Just Google for it!

Comment: Your second and fourth regexes contradict the first regex.  Also, the OP said **up to** eight characters, not *at least* eight.

Comment: Also, let's not do his job for him.

Comment: As per my post I suspect my first being a "not" type match contradicts all the other three!  As I said I dont know how (or evenif) you can combine all of the rquirments into one regex. That said I thought some answeres will help the OP along!

Answer (score 1):

First hit in google for ["password validation regular expression"](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/)

gives us the

```
^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

which

- Must be at least 10 characters
- Must contain at least one one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character
- Valid special characters are - @#$%^&+=

now that will just need adapting for 8 chars (minimum) and to not have number at the beginning and the end and no uppercase and start with a letter

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])([a-z][^0-9A-Z])[^A-Z]*[^0-9A-Z]$
```

which was tested online at [RegExPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html)

```
1       a1@aaaaa        Yes 
2       a1@aaaaaaa      Yes
3       a1@aaaa         No
4       1a@aaaaa        No  
5       aa@aaaa1        No  
6       Aa@aa1aa        No  
7       aa@a1aaA        No  
8       aA@a1aaa        No  
9       #A@a1aaaaa      No
```

I recommend you read the first article as to how this was constructed (I learnt a lot) and use the second link (though there are many other online regex testers) to play with regular expressions without having to compile code all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-z][a-z\d!@#$%\^&*()\-+]{0,7}$(?<=\d\D+)");
bool isValid = regex.IsMatch(password);
```

- “Not have upper-case letters.” – Do not match `A-Z` or `\w` anywhere within your regex.
- “Begin with a letter.” – Match `^[a-z]`. `^` is the start-of-string anchor.
- “Have up to 8 alphanumeric or @#$ characters (symbols like !@#$%^&*()-+).” – `[a-z\d]{0,7}` matches 0–7 alphanumeric characters. (This first letter would have been matched by the preceding `[a-z]`.) Any additional allowed characters may also be specified within the character class. `^` and `-` need to be escaped.
- “Have at least 1 digit(s) not at the beginning and end.” – Use negated lookbehind: `(?<=\d\D+)`. `\d\D+` means a digit following by one or more non-digits. A digit may not occur at the beginning due to the second condition.